# Debugging a package during component installation

Tags: delphi, debugging, c++builder, delphi-xe5, rad-studio

I need to build old components made for BCB6 (Borland C++ Builder 6) in Embarcadero RAD Studio XE5. Projects are CPP- projects, and the component code is contained in the *.PAS - files.
The project contain 6 packages:

- three packages a design time
- three packages runtime

First I build packages runtime. After that I start building and installing the packages design time that use packages runtime. And one design time package has a problem during installation:

[image]

I found a runtime package that causes this problem. My question is how do I find and resolve the following error? After all, when the package is installed, I cannot start the debugger, see the stack trace, nothing at all. What are the options? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For that you need to run a second instance of the IDE in the debugger:

- Uninstall the packages
- Compile all packages with debug information
- Load the project of the runtime package that causes the problem
- In Run -> Parameters Set the Host application to $(BDS)\Bin\bds.exe
- Press run with debug
- This will start a second instance of the IDE. You might have to ignore some exceptions that it internally raises (and handles).
- In that second instance, load the design time package which loads the runtime package that causes the problem
- Hopefully you will now see what happens

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try and be sure to tell you about the results.

Comment: @Range Man, I would love to hear those results...