# Problems debugging runtime package

Tags: delphi, debugging, c++builder, delphi-xe5, rad-studio

This question founded on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969608/debugging-a-package-during-component-installation/62971501#62971501). My IDE - RAD Studio XE 5 Architect Update 2. My problem:

When installing a design-time package, an exception is thrown in the run-time package being used. To do this, I need to debug this runtime package. When trying to debug package the breakpoint is always green color and in event log print text: 'No debug info'.
My steps:

- Open IDE and download the problematic runtime package
- Assign a host to it with the IDE application
- Start debugging
- Wait for the second copy of IDE to start
- On a new IDE instance, open the design-time package that is causing the problem
- Start installing a design-time package

I see stack trace and exception, but breakpoint not working.

I maked test and created project group:

- Probleming runtime package
- Test application (VCL exe) from one procedure, which through procedure
  *LoadPackage* loading probleming runtime package
- Set breakpoint in problem runtime package
- Run debugger

Wonderful! Breakpoint is worked!

My question: how to make works breakpoint at debugging probleming runtime package through host application (IDE second instance)?

Thanks.

P.S.:
Properties my runtime package:

- Project Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Compiler -> Assertions -> True
- Project Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Compiler -> Debug information -> Debug information
- Project Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Compiler -> Local symbols -> True
- Project Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Compiler -> Symbol reference info -> Reference info
- Project Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Compiler -> Use debug .dcus -> True
- Project Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Linking -> Debug information -> True
- Project Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Linking -> Include remote debug symbols -> True
- Project Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Linking -> Map file -> Publics
- Project Options -> C++ Compiler -> Debugging-> Debug information -> True
- Project Options -> C++ Compiler -> Debugging-> Debug line number information -> True

On output I have files: *.bpi, *.bpl, *.drc, *.lib, *.map, *.pdi, *.tds .

P.S.S.:
when debugging with a project group, no exception is thrown, the problem only appears WHEN installing a design-time package

**UPD 1:**

I saw some kind of pattern. The * .dpk (delphi) project is debugged without problems. A project is a project *.cbproj (cpp) has problems with debugging. Here is a list of files:

Project test_runtime_package.dpk, include files:

- test_runtime_package.dproj
- test_runtime_package_delphi.pas

**test_runtime_package.dpk**

```
package test_runtime_package;

{$R *.res}
{$IFDEF IMPLICITBUILDING This IFDEF should not be used by users}
{$ALIGN 8}
{$ASSERTIONS ON}
{$BOOLEVAL OFF}
{$DEBUGINFO ON}
{$EXTENDEDSYNTAX ON}
{$IMPORTEDDATA ON}
{$IOCHECKS ON}
{$LOCALSYMBOLS ON}
{$LONGSTRINGS ON}
{$OPENSTRINGS ON}
{$OPTIMIZATION OFF}
{$OVERFLOWCHECKS OFF}
{$RANGECHECKS OFF}
{$REFERENCEINFO ON}
{$SAFEDIVIDE OFF}
{$STACKFRAMES ON}
{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}
{$VARSTRINGCHECKS ON}
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
{$MINENUMSIZE 1}
{$IMAGEBASE $400000}
{$DEFINE DEBUG}
{$ENDIF IMPLICITBUILDING}
{$DESCRIPTION 'test_runtime_package'}
{$RUNONLY}
{$IMPLICITBUILD OFF}

requires
  rtl,
  vcl;

contains
  test_runtime_package_delphi in 'test_runtime_package_delphi.pas';

end.
```

**test_runtime_package.dproj**

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ProjectGuid>{F046793E-2171-4D64-8090-C673864791BC}</ProjectGuid>
        <MainSource>test_runtime_package.dpk</MainSource>
        <ProjectVersion>15.3</ProjectVersion>
        <FrameworkType>None</FrameworkType>
        <Base>True</Base>
        <Config Condition="'$(Config)'==''">Debug</Config>
        <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)'==''">Win32</Platform>
        <TargetedPlatforms>1</TargetedPlatforms>
        <AppType>Package</AppType>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Base' or '$(Base)'!=''">
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Win32' and '$(Base)'=='true') or '$(Base_Win32)'!=''">
        <Base_Win32>true</Base_Win32>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Debug' or '$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
        <Cfg_1>true</Cfg_1>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Win32' and '$(Cfg_1)'=='true') or '$(Cfg_1_Win32)'!=''">
        <Cfg_1_Win32>true</Cfg_1_Win32>
        <CfgParent>Cfg_1</CfgParent>
        <Cfg_1>true</Cfg_1>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Release' or '$(Cfg_2)'!=''">
        <Cfg_2>true</Cfg_2>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base)'!=''">
        <GenDll>true</GenDll>
        <DCC_CBuilderOutput>All</DCC_CBuilderOutput>
        <RuntimeOnlyPackage>true</RuntimeOnlyPackage>
        <DCC_OutputNeverBuildDcps>true</DCC_OutputNeverBuildDcps>
        <DCC_Namespace>System;Xml;Data;Datasnap;Web;Soap;Vcl;Vcl.Imaging;Vcl.Touch;Vcl.Samples;Vcl.Shell;$(DCC_Namespace)</DCC_Namespace>
        <GenPackage>true</GenPackage>
        <DCC_DcuOutput>.\$(Platform)\$(Config)</DCC_DcuOutput>
        <DCC_ExeOutput>.\$(Platform)\$(Config)</DCC_ExeOutput>
        <DCC_E>false</DCC_E>
        <DCC_N>false</DCC_N>
        <DCC_S>false</DCC_S>
        <DCC_F>false</DCC_F>
        <DCC_K>false</DCC_K>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base_Win32)'!=''">
        <VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>true</VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>
        <VerInfo_Locale>1033</VerInfo_Locale>
        <DCC_Namespace>Winapi;System.Win;Data.Win;Datasnap.Win;Web.Win;Soap.Win;Xml.Win;Bde;$(DCC_Namespace)</DCC_Namespace>
        <VerInfo_Keys>CompanyName=;FileDescription=;FileVersion=1.0.0.0;InternalName=;LegalCopyright=;LegalTrademarks=;OriginalFilename=;ProductName=;ProductVersion=1.0.0.0;Comments=</VerInfo_Keys>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
        <DCC_Define>DEBUG;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
        <DCC_DebugDCUs>true</DCC_DebugDCUs>
        <DCC_Optimize>false</DCC_Optimize>
        <DCC_GenerateStackFrames>true</DCC_GenerateStackFrames>
        <DCC_DebugInfoInExe>true</DCC_DebugInfoInExe>
        <DCC_RemoteDebug>true</DCC_RemoteDebug>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1_Win32)'!=''">
        <Debugger_HostApplication>C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\bin\bds.exe</Debugger_HostApplication>
        <VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>true</VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>
        <VerInfo_Locale>1033</VerInfo_Locale>
        <DCC_Description>test_runtime_package</DCC_Description>
        <DCC_RemoteDebug>false</DCC_RemoteDebug>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_2)'!=''">
        <DCC_LocalDebugSymbols>false</DCC_LocalDebugSymbols>
        <DCC_Define>RELEASE;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
        <DCC_SymbolReferenceInfo>0</DCC_SymbolReferenceInfo>
        <DCC_DebugInformation>0</DCC_DebugInformation>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <DelphiCompile Include="$(MainSource)">
            <MainSource>MainSource</MainSource>
        </DelphiCompile>
        <DCCReference Include="rtl.dcp"/>
        <DCCReference Include="vcl.dcp"/>
        <DCCReference Include="test_runtime_package_delphi.pas"/>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Release">
            <Key>Cfg_2</Key>
            <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        </BuildConfiguration>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Base">
            <Key>Base</Key>
        </BuildConfiguration>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Debug">
            <Key>Cfg_1</Key>
            <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        </BuildConfiguration>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ProjectExtensions>
        <Borland.Personality>Delphi.Personality.12</Borland.Personality>
        <Borland.ProjectType>Package</Borland.ProjectType>
        <BorlandProject>
            <Delphi.Personality>
                <Source>
                    <Source Name="MainSource">test_runtime_package.dpk</Source>
                </Source>
                <VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="IncludeVerInfo">True</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="AutoIncBuild">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="MajorVer">1</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="MinorVer">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Release">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Build">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Debug">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="PreRelease">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Special">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Private">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="DLL">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Locale">1049</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="CodePage">1251</VersionInfo>
                </VersionInfo>
                <VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CompanyName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="FileDescription"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="FileVersion">1.0.0.0</VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="InternalName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LegalCopyright"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LegalTrademarks"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="OriginalFilename"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="ProductName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="ProductVersion">1.0.0.0</VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="Comments"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleDisplayName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="UIDeviceFamily"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleIdentifier"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleVersion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundlePackageType"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleSignature"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleExecutable"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleResourceSpecification"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LSRequiresIPhoneOS"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="package"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="label"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="versionCode"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="versionName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="persistent"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="restoreAnyVersion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="installLocation"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="largeHeap"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="theme"/>
                </VersionInfoKeys>
                <Excluded_Packages>
                    <Excluded_Packages Name="$(BDSBIN)\bcboffice2k190.bpl">Embarcadero C++Builder Office 2000 Servers Package</Excluded_Packages>
                    <Excluded_Packages Name="$(BDSBIN)\bcbofficexp190.bpl">Embarcadero C++Builder Office XP Servers Package</Excluded_Packages>
                    <Excluded_Packages Name="$(BDSBIN)\dcloffice2k190.bpl">Microsoft Office 2000 Sample Automation Server Wrapper Components</Excluded_Packages>
                    <Excluded_Packages Name="$(BDSBIN)\dclofficexp190.bpl">Microsoft Office XP Sample Automation Server Wrapper Components</Excluded_Packages>
                </Excluded_Packages>
            </Delphi.Personality>
            <Deployment/>
            <Platforms>
                <Platform value="Win32">True</Platform>
                <Platform value="Win64">False</Platform>
            </Platforms>
        </BorlandProject>
        <ProjectFileVersion>12</ProjectFileVersion>
    </ProjectExtensions>
    <Import Project="$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets" Condition="Exists('$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets')"/>
    <Import Project="$(APPDATA)\Embarcadero\$(BDSAPPDATABASEDIR)\$(PRODUCTVERSION)\UserTools.proj" Condition="Exists('$(APPDATA)\Embarcadero\$(BDSAPPDATABASEDIR)\$(PRODUCTVERSION)\UserTools.proj')"/>
</Project>
```

**test_runtime_package_delphi.pas**

```
unit test_runtime_package_delphi;

interface

uses Vcl.Dialogs;

type
   TStringTest = Class

     private

     published
       constructor Create(Text : String);
   end;

implementation

constructor TStringTest.Create(Text: String);
var
str: String;
 begin
   ShowMessage(Text);
   str         := Text;
 end;


end.
```

Project test_runtime_package.cbproj, include files:

- test_runtime_package.cpp
- test_runtime_package_delphi.pas

**test_runtime_package.cbproj**

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ProjectGuid>{C6C68C4D-7E20-441B-A166-E18E74DCF4E3}</ProjectGuid>
        <ProjectVersion>15.3</ProjectVersion>
        <FrameworkType>None</FrameworkType>
        <MainSource>test_runtime_package.cpp</MainSource>
        <Base>True</Base>
        <Config Condition="'$(Config)'==''">Debug</Config>
        <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)'==''">Win32</Platform>
        <TargetedPlatforms>1</TargetedPlatforms>
        <AppType>Package</AppType>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Base' or '$(Base)'!=''">
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Win32' and '$(Base)'=='true') or '$(Base_Win32)'!=''">
        <Base_Win32>true</Base_Win32>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Debug' or '$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
        <Cfg_1>true</Cfg_1>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Win32' and '$(Cfg_1)'=='true') or '$(Cfg_1_Win32)'!=''">
        <Cfg_1_Win32>true</Cfg_1_Win32>
        <CfgParent>Cfg_1</CfgParent>
        <Cfg_1>true</Cfg_1>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Release' or '$(Cfg_2)'!=''">
        <Cfg_2>true</Cfg_2>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base)'!=''">
        <RuntimeOnlyPackage>true</RuntimeOnlyPackage>
        <ILINK_GenerateLibFile>true</ILINK_GenerateLibFile>
        <_TCHARMapping>char</_TCHARMapping>
        <DCC_OutputNeverBuildDcps>true</DCC_OutputNeverBuildDcps>
        <ILINK_GenerateImportLibrary>true</ILINK_GenerateImportLibrary>
        <Multithreaded>true</Multithreaded>
        <DCC_Namespace>System;Xml;Data;Datasnap;Web;Soap;$(DCC_Namespace)</DCC_Namespace>
        <ProjectType>CppPackage</ProjectType>
        <DCC_CBuilderOutput>JPHNE</DCC_CBuilderOutput>
        <DynamicRTL>true</DynamicRTL>
        <UsePackages>true</UsePackages>
        <IntermediateOutputDir>.\$(Platform)\$(Config)</IntermediateOutputDir>
        <BCC_wpar>false</BCC_wpar>
        <BCC_OptimizeForSpeed>true</BCC_OptimizeForSpeed>
        <BCC_ExtendedErrorInfo>true</BCC_ExtendedErrorInfo>
        <ILINK_TranslatedLibraryPath>$(BDSLIB)\$(PLATFORM)\release\$(LANGDIR);$(ILINK_TranslatedLibraryPath)</ILINK_TranslatedLibraryPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base_Win32)'!=''">
        <PackageImports>adortl;bcbie;bcbsmp;bdertl;bindcomp;bindcompdbx;bindcompfmx;bindcompvcl;bindengine;CloudService;CodeSiteExpressPkg;CustomIPTransport;DataSnapClient;DataSnapCommon;DataSnapConnectors;DatasnapConnectorsFreePascal;DataSnapFireDAC;DataSnapIndy10ServerTransport;DataSnapProviderClient;DataSnapServer;dbexpress;dbrtl;dbxcds;DbxClientDriver;DbxCommonDriver;DBXDb2Driver;DBXFirebirdDriver;DBXInformixDriver;DBXInterBaseDriver;DBXMSSQLDriver;DBXMySQLDriver;DBXOdbcDriver;DBXOracleDriver;DBXSqliteDriver;DBXSybaseASADriver;DBXSybaseASEDriver;dsnap;dsnapcon;FireDAC;FireDACADSDriver;FireDACASADriver;FireDACCommon;FireDACCommonDriver;FireDACDataSnapDriver;FireDACDb2Driver;FireDACDBXDriver;FireDACIBDriver;FireDACMSAccDriver;FireDACMSSQLDriver;FireDACMySQLDriver;FireDACODBCDriver;FireDACOracleDriver;FireDACPgDriver;FireDACSqliteDriver;fmx;fmxase;fmxdae;fmxFireDAC;fmxobj;FMXTee;FmxTeeUI;frx19;frxDB19;frxe19;ibxpress;IndyCore;IndyIPClient;IndyIPCommon;IndyIPServer;IndyProtocols;IndySystem;inet;inetdb;inetdbbde;inetdbxpress;Intraweb;MetropolisUILiveTile;RESTComponents;rtl;soaprtl;svn;Tee;TeeDB;TeeUI;vcl;vclactnband;vcldb;vcldbx;vcldsnap;vclFireDAC;vclib;vclie;vclimg;VCLRESTComponents;vclribbon;VclSmp;vcltouch;vclx;xmlrtl;$(PackageImports)</PackageImports>
        <VerInfo_Locale>1033</VerInfo_Locale>
        <VerInfo_Keys>CompanyName=;FileDescription=;FileVersion=1.0.0.0;InternalName=;LegalCopyright=;LegalTrademarks=;OriginalFilename=;ProductName=;ProductVersion=1.0.0.0;Comments=</VerInfo_Keys>
        <VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>true</VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>
        <DCC_Namespace>Winapi;System.Win;Data.Win;Datasnap.Win;Web.Win;Soap.Win;Xml.Win;Bde;$(DCC_Namespace)</DCC_Namespace>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
        <BCC_OptimizeForSpeed>false</BCC_OptimizeForSpeed>
        <BCC_DisableOptimizations>true</BCC_DisableOptimizations>
        <DCC_Optimize>false</DCC_Optimize>
        <DCC_DebugInfoInExe>true</DCC_DebugInfoInExe>
        <Defines>_DEBUG;$(Defines)</Defines>
        <BCC_InlineFunctionExpansion>false</BCC_InlineFunctionExpansion>
        <BCC_UseRegisterVariables>None</BCC_UseRegisterVariables>
        <DCC_Define>DEBUG</DCC_Define>
        <BCC_DebugLineNumbers>true</BCC_DebugLineNumbers>
        <TASM_DisplaySourceLines>true</TASM_DisplaySourceLines>
        <BCC_StackFrames>true</BCC_StackFrames>
        <ILINK_FullDebugInfo>true</ILINK_FullDebugInfo>
        <TASM_Debugging>Full</TASM_Debugging>
        <BCC_SourceDebuggingOn>true</BCC_SourceDebuggingOn>
        <BCC_EnableCPPExceptions>true</BCC_EnableCPPExceptions>
        <BCC_DisableFramePtrElimOpt>true</BCC_DisableFramePtrElimOpt>
        <BCC_DisableSpellChecking>true</BCC_DisableSpellChecking>
        <CLANG_UnwindTables>true</CLANG_UnwindTables>
        <ILINK_LibraryPath>$(BDSLIB)\$(PLATFORM)\debug;$(ILINK_LibraryPath)</ILINK_LibraryPath>
        <ILINK_TranslatedLibraryPath>$(BDSLIB)\$(PLATFORM)\debug\$(LANGDIR);$(ILINK_TranslatedLibraryPath)</ILINK_TranslatedLibraryPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1_Win32)'!=''">
        <Debugger_HostApplication>C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\bin\bds.exe</Debugger_HostApplication>
        <BPILibOutputDir>.\</BPILibOutputDir>
        <ILINK_Description>test_runtime_package</ILINK_Description>
        <VerInfo_Locale>1033</VerInfo_Locale>
        <VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>true</VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_2)'!=''">
        <Defines>NDEBUG;$(Defines)</Defines>
        <TASM_Debugging>None</TASM_Debugging>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageImport Include="rtl.bpi">
            <BuildOrder>1</BuildOrder>
        </PackageImport>
        <CppCompile Include="test_runtime_package.cpp">
            <BuildOrder>0</BuildOrder>
        </CppCompile>
        <DelphiCompile Include="test_runtime_package_delphi.pas">
            <BuildOrder>3</BuildOrder>
        </DelphiCompile>
        <PackageImport Include="vcl.bpi">
            <BuildOrder>4</BuildOrder>
        </PackageImport>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Release">
            <Key>Cfg_2</Key>
            <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        </BuildConfiguration>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Base">
            <Key>Base</Key>
        </BuildConfiguration>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Debug">
            <Key>Cfg_1</Key>
            <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        </BuildConfiguration>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ProjectExtensions>
        <Borland.Personality>CPlusPlusBuilder.Personality.12</Borland.Personality>
        <Borland.ProjectType>CppPackage</Borland.ProjectType>
        <BorlandProject>
            <CPlusPlusBuilder.Personality>
                <Source>
                    <Source Name="MainSource">test_runtime_package.cpp</Source>
                </Source>
                <VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="IncludeVerInfo">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="AutoIncBuild">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="MajorVer">1</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="MinorVer">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Release">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Build">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Debug">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="PreRelease">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Special">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Private">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="DLL">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Locale">1049</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="CodePage">1251</VersionInfo>
                </VersionInfo>
                <VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CompanyName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="FileDescription"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="FileVersion">1.0.0.0</VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="InternalName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LegalCopyright"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LegalTrademarks"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="OriginalFilename"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="ProductName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="ProductVersion">1.0.0.0</VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="Comments"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleDisplayName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="UIDeviceFamily"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleIdentifier"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleVersion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundlePackageType"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleSignature"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleExecutable"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleResourceSpecification"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LSRequiresIPhoneOS"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="package"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="label"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="versionCode"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="versionName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="persistent"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="restoreAnyVersion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="installLocation"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="largeHeap"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="theme"/>
                </VersionInfoKeys>
                <ProjectProperties>
                    <ProjectProperties Name="AutoShowDeps">False</ProjectProperties>
                    <ProjectProperties Name="ManagePaths">True</ProjectProperties>
                    <ProjectProperties Name="VerifyPackages">True</ProjectProperties>
                </ProjectProperties>
                <Excluded_Packages>
                    <Excluded_Packages Name="$(BDSBIN)\bcboffice2k190.bpl">Embarcadero C++Builder Office 2000 Servers Package</Excluded_Packages>
                    <Excluded_Packages Name="$(BDSBIN)\bcbofficexp190.bpl">Embarcadero C++Builder Office XP Servers Package</Excluded_Packages>
                    <Excluded_Packages Name="$(BDSBIN)\dcloffice2k190.bpl">Microsoft Office 2000 Sample Automation Server Wrapper Components</Excluded_Packages>
                    <Excluded_Packages Name="$(BDSBIN)\dclofficexp190.bpl">Microsoft Office XP Sample Automation Server Wrapper Components</Excluded_Packages>
                </Excluded_Packages>
            </CPlusPlusBuilder.Personality>
            <Deployment/>
            <Platforms>
                <Platform value="Win32">True</Platform>
            </Platforms>
        </BorlandProject>
        <ProjectFileVersion>12</ProjectFileVersion>
    </ProjectExtensions>
    <Import Project="$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets" Condition="Exists('$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets')"/>
    <Import Project="$(APPDATA)\Embarcadero\$(BDSAPPDATABASEDIR)\$(PRODUCTVERSION)\UserTools.proj" Condition="Exists('$(APPDATA)\Embarcadero\$(BDSAPPDATABASEDIR)\$(PRODUCTVERSION)\UserTools.proj')"/>
</Project>
```

**test_runtime_package.cpp**

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma package(smart_init)

int WINAPI DllEntryPoint(HINSTANCE hinst, unsigned long reason, void*)
{
    return 1;
}
```

File test_runtime_package_delphi.pas the same as in the project test_runtime_package.dpk.

Comment: The method described by @dummzeuch in the linked answer works fine, and I have used it many times myself.  A few times I have had the "main" IDE instance not stop on the breakpoints when the second instance loads the package being debugged.  When that happens, it is usually fixed by the following: 1.  Close both instances of the IDE.  2.  Delete the .Bpl file of the package.  3. Restart the IDE.  4. Open the Bpl's .Dpk file as the IDE's project & recompile.  5.  Set breakpoints then start 2nd IDE instance.

Comment: PS, if you want more help, you will need to provide a minimal dt unit + .Dpk which replicates the problem you're having.

Comment: @MartynA I update my question (UPD1)